# How to get X509 Certificate for Windows Azure Management API?

Tags: c#, azure, x509certificate, azure-management-api

I'm having difficulty connecting to the Windows Azure Management APIs I believe it's because I don't have the correct X509 cert information.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/How-to-create-a-Azure-SQL-5157ce03

I've tried creating my own self-signed certificate and uploading it to Azure and then copying the thumbprint from the cert but I get the error below.

Here is my code:

```
public class CreateAzureDatabase {

    protected static string subscriptionId = "{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}";
    protected static string serverName = "xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net";
    public static string base64EncodedCertificate = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    public void DoDatabase(string newDatabaseName) {

        SqlManagementClient client = new SqlManagementClient(getCredentials());
        //Server Name is your SQL Azure DataBase server name, for example:da0dt6hrt6 
        client.Databases.Create(serverName, new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql.Models.DatabaseCreateParameters() {
            Name = newDatabaseName,
            MaximumDatabaseSizeInGB = 1,
            CollationName = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
        });

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
    static SubscriptionCloudCredentials getCredentials() {
        return new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedCertificate)));
    } 

}
```

The error I get is: *CryptographicException*

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Cannot find the requested object.
```

**Why is this error happening?**

**How do I get the correct base64EncodedCertificate for my Azure portal?**

Comment: From where are you getting `base64EncodedCertificate`?

Comment: @GauravMantri I tried to upload a test self cert and I used the thumbprint that Azure shows but I got this error. I'm also trying to follow this tutorial: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/How-to-create-a-Azure-SQL-5157ce03

Comment: I don't actually know where I should go or what I should do to get the base64EncodedCertificate

Comment: Do one thing. Download `Azure Publish Settings File` (https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index). Open this file in Notepad or any other text editor. You will find the base64 encoded certificate in `ManagementCertificate` node. HTH.

Comment: Thank you so much @GauravMantri that's got me past the Certificate error, I now have another error: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudException'  ResourceNotFound: The Uri doesn't match any specific service operation.

Comment: I believe you just have to specify the server name in your `serverName` variable. Can you try again by dropping `database.windows.net` from there?